# joomla: adding a select.optgroup to select.genericlist

Tags: php, joomla, optgroup

I need to add a select.optgroup to my select.genericlist, this is my code:

```
foreach ($this->methods as $method) {
      if ($this->checkConditions($cart, $method, $cart->pricesUnformatted)) {
          $methodSalesPrice = $this->calculateSalesPrice($cart, $method, $cart->pricesUnformatted);
          $method->$method_name = $this->renderPluginName($method);

              $session = JFactory::getSession();
              $htmlI[] = $this->getPluginHtml($method, $selected, $methodSalesPrice);
              // this is my attempt
              $htmlI[] = JHTML::_('Select.optgroup', 'My optgroup');
              // my attempt ends here
              $htmlI[] = JHTML::_('Select.genericlist', $this->banks, 'service_issuer', 'size=1', 'key', 'value', $session->get('service_issuer', 0, 'vm'));
              $html[] = $htmlI;


      }
  }
```

this returns the following:

```
array
```

Has anyone done this before? Advice is much appreciated

Comment: which line gives you error?

Comment: the attempt: $htmlI .= JHTML::_('Select.optgroup', 'My optgroup');

Comment: JHTML returns an object, not a string, so you have to do `htmlI[] = JHTML...`, and change the rest of the code accordingly

Comment: @MarkoD thanks for your help Marko, please see the updated code, it just returns 'array' now. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well, depends what are you supposed to do with that array. what do you expect `$html` to output, and how are you outputing it?

Comment: it should output a selectlist with grouping, without the 'attempt' line, it displays correctly, when I add your suggestions, it outputs 'array'

Comment: I think I understand the problem. Can you just tell me what does `var_dump($banks)` return?

Comment: var_dump($banks) returns NULL - var_dump($this->banks) returns an array with keys and its values, like this: array(11) { [0]=> array(2) { ["key"]=> string(1) "0" ["value"]=> string(22) "-- Select your bank --" } [1]=> array(2) { ["key"]=> string(8) "dsads" ["value"]=> string(8) "bank 1" }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25366/discussion-between-marko-d-and-maarten-hartman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix it myself,  below is the working code

```
if($method->payment_method == "mymethod") {
              $session = JFactory::getSession();
              $htmlI = $this->getPluginHtml($method, $selected, $methodSalesPrice);
              $banksEra[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '', JText::_('VMPAYMENT_BANKS'));
              $banksEra[] = JHTML::_('select.optgroup', 'Countries');
              foreach ($this->banksEra as $key => $value) {
                $banksEra[] = JHTML::_( 'select.option', $key, $value );
              }
              $htmlI .= JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $banksEra, 'issuer', 'class="inputbox"', 'value', 'text', $session->get('issuer', 0, 'vm'));
              $html[] = $htmlI;
          }
```